# OpenID + API REST + Node Server

Tags: node.js, spring, rest, api, openid-connect

I have a reactjs project (running on port 3000), a JAVA API REST with Spring (running on 8080) and I have to configure it to work with an OpenID server.

I'm able to login to the OpenId from the front-end project (using Implicit Flow), but if I try to access the API, this throws me a 302 and tries me to redirect to the login page of the Auth server.

I have installed pac4 in the API.

How Can I send something to the API and how can I configure the API to validate this token? Because now, the API is answering a 302 to the login page of the OpenId.

The idea of my question is to know if I can do the following thing:

1- Login to the OpenId from the Node server.

2- Send the id_token to the API Rest

3- The API REST validates this token (I think against OpenId Server)

4- If the token is valid, return the petition.

Thanks!

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: It's more like a theorical question. Is it okay to use an access_token to login in the Front-End project and validate this access_token in the backend? Is this the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I saw a lot of people with the same problem or doubt so I'll post my solution.

I used for the front-end project an openId javascript client account. You need to ask for "token id_token". This means it will retrieve the access_token in the callback.

With this access_token, you can hit the API. 
I used HeaderClient (pac4j library), and I send the access_token in the header as "Authorization": "Bearer ...".

In the API I created an interceptor and added the following validation:

```
final HeaderClient headerClient = new HeaderClient("Authorization", "Bearer " ,  (credentials, ctx) -> {
            final String token = ((TokenCredentials) credentials).getToken();
            JWSAlgorithm jwsAlg = JWSAlgorithm.RS256;
            try {
                URL jwkSetURL = new URL(authority + jwks);
                try {
                    if (CommonHelper.isNotBlank(token)) {
                        // Set up a JWT processor to parse the tokens and then check their signature
                        // and validity time window (bounded by the "iat", "nbf" and "exp" claims)
                        ConfigurableJWTProcessor jwtProcessor = new DefaultJWTProcessor();
                        // The public RSA keys to validate the signatures will be sourced from the
                        // OAuth 2.0 server's JWK set, published at a well-known URL. The RemoteJWKSet
                        // object caches the retrieved keys to speed up subsequent look-ups and can
                        // also gracefully handle key-rollover
                        JWKSource keySource = new RemoteJWKSet(jwkSetURL , new DefaultResourceRetriever() );
                        // Configure the JWT processor with a key selector to feed matching public
                        // RSA keys sourced from the JWK set URL
                        JWSKeySelector keySelector = new JWSVerificationKeySelector(jwsAlg, keySource);
                        jwtProcessor.setJWSKeySelector(keySelector);
                        // Process the token
                        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = jwtProcessor.process(token, null);
                        // Print out the token claims set
                        if (claimsSet != null) {
                            CommonProfile profile = new CommonProfile();
                            profile.setId(token);
                            // save in the credentials to be passed to the default AuthenticatorProfileCreator
                            credentials.setUserProfile(profile);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (BadJOSEException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Authorization token");
                } catch (JOSEException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error on Authorization token");
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
```